# How do I properly set up the legend to my linear mixed model using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I have built a linear mixed effects model and I'm trying to plot it using `ggplot` but it keeps giving me  problems with my legend. It's `ordered` wrong, or I get two legends, or the symbols get mixed up, or a combination of all three. This is driving me insane and I can't believe that it's this complicated. Here's my code:

```
g1 <-  ggplot(SpotGrowth_longform, 
              aes(x = spotage, y = spotprop, color = treatment)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = treatment)) +
  labs(x = "Hours Since White Spot First Detected", 
       y = "Proportion of Egg Surface Area") +
  guides(color = guide_legend("% Oxygen")) +
  theme_classic() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE) +
  theme(legend.position = c(.1, .8)) +
  scale_color_manual("% Oxygen", values = c("red", "orange", "green", "blue","black"))
g1
```

My independent variables/fixed effects are `spotage` and `treatment`. The dependent variable is `spotprop`. Also, `treatment` is a grouping factor (% oxygen) that I used for the mixed effect analysis. `spotage` and `spotprop` are numeric fields, `treatment` is a factor.
The code above give me this chart (can't post image?):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OWpESx0ES_5ha2rL75pHDtWoj1HcKgd0/view?usp=sharing

I feel like I'm almost there because all I want is to make the lower legend, the one titled "% Oxygen" that also has the shading for the CIs, show the shapes that are called out in the upper legend - and I'd like to have them ordered descending so they match the chart, and, if possible, show significant differences between groups with letters or stars or whatever. Obviously I am missing something important but nothing I've read online solves this exact problem.
I guess I should mention that I would prefer not to use colors at all, that's why I want to have unique point shapes for each `treatment`.
I will share the data with the forum if someone will tell me how to do it. It is formatted long form and has 487 rows of data.

Comment: To add data, the easiest thing is to run `dput(SpotGrowth)` and paste the code that results. That code will create an EXACT copy of your data table with the same data formats and everything. you probably only need a sample, e.g. `dput(head(SpotGrowth,50))` or adjust to taste.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a line `guides(shape = guide_legend("% Oxygen")) +` where the shape legend name matches the color legend name for them to be combined.

Here an example using mtcars data to be reproducible:

```
ggplot(mtcars, 
       aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = as.character(cyl))) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = as.character(cyl)), size = 5) +
  labs(x = "Hours Since White Spot First Detected", 
       y = "Proportion of Egg Surface Area") +
  guides(color = guide_legend("% Oxygen", reverse = TRUE),
         shape = guide_legend("% Oxygen", reverse = TRUE)) +
  theme_classic() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE) +
  
  theme(legend.position = c(.5, .8)) +
  scale_color_manual("% Oxygen", values = c("gray80", "gray50", "gray20"))
```

[image]

Comment: You might also want to add `reverse = TRUE` in your `guide_legend()` calls, to reverse the order of the series displayed in the legend.

Comment: Thank you! This worked exactly as described to put everything in one legend. Now I just need to figure out how to insert the `reverse = TRUE` statement in my `guide_legend()` and put everything in grayscale. Thanks again!

Comment: See edit, demonstrates those changes.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have made my life better :)